# How to turn JSON to object literal using PHP and jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is there a concise neat way to turn an XML feed into an JavaScript object literal?

I have this XML feed

```
<jobs>
    <industry>
        <name>Technology</name>
        <area>Refrigiration</area>
        <area>Information Technology</area>
        <area>Electronics</area>
        <area>Avionics</area>
    </industry>

    <industry>
        <name>Agriculture</name>
        <area>Agri-Tourism</area>
        <area>Animal Husbandry</area>
        <area>Harvesting</area>
        <area>Poultry</area>
    </industry>
</jobs>
```

and wish to turn it to:

```
var jobs = [
    {
        "name"  : "Technology",
        "areas" : [ "Refrigiration" , "Information Technology", "Electronics", "Avionics" ]
    },

    {
        "name"  : "Agriculture",
        "areas" : [ "Agri-Tourism" , "Animal Husbandry", "Harvesting", "Poultry" ]      
    },

    {
        "name"  : "Media",
        "areas" : [ "Journalism" , "Camera person", "Reality tv person", "Commentator" ]        
    }       
];
```

I succeeded in encoding the JSON object using php. What I am missing is the rest.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself several times in this question. What are you trying to do exactly and what did and didn't you succeed in?

Comment: What is "the rest"? Do you want to send this to the client and display it?

Comment: WTF do you mean "using PHP *and* jQuery" - do you want to do it serverside or not?

Comment: I first grabbed the XML feed using an Ajax request getJSON(). The rest would be turning it into an object literal.

Comment: If you're fetching XML, then why use `getJSON`? JSON is a data interchange format that is distinct from the XML format.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo json_encode(simplexml_load_string("<jobs>
    <industry>
        <name>Technology</name>
        <area>Refrigiration</area>
        <area>Information Technology</area>
        <area>Electronics</area>
        <area>Avionics</area>
    </industry>

    <industry>
        <name>Agriculture</name>
        <area>Agri-Tourism</area>
        <area>Animal Husbandry</area>
        <area>Harvesting</area>
        <area>Poultry</area>
    </industry>
</jobs>"));
```

This gives you:

```
{
    "industry": [
        {
            "name": "Technology",
            "area": [
                "Refrigiration",
                "Information Technology",
                "Electronics",
                "Avionics"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Agriculture",
            "area": [
                "Agri-Tourism",
                "Animal Husbandry",
                "Harvesting",
                "Poultry"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: and how do I pass an XML file as parameter instead of plain XML?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your XML to an array, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844476/xml-to-php-array

Then you'll need to convert the array to json using php json_encode()

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

**PURE JQUERY**

Using [jQuery's parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) , combined with [jQuery get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) you can have the object you need:

```
$.get("http://www.example.com/path/to/file.xml", function(data){
   var xml = $.parseXML(data);
   console.log(xml);
});
```

**PHP+JQUERY**

if you've already parsed the object into a json, just print it into an html file and get that file using [jquery's getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

```
$.getJSON("http://www.example.com/json/feed",function(data){
   console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving a JSON encoded string in your javascript callback, you probably need to run $.parseJSON() to make jQuery treat it as a JSON object instead of a string